# SQL Server 2008 Master/Detail ( Using Delphi and ADOQuery )

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-2010, master-detail, tadoquery

I have a SQL Server 2008 DataBase with 2 Table : Master and Detail

Master Fields : ID and ... ;

Detail Fields : ID , MasterID and ... ;

I have been set the relationship between Master and Detail in SQL Server

I want when I Select a record in Master DBGrid , Detail Query returns only records related to selected Master Record and Detail DBGrid Show only Related records

I dont want to Requery Detail ADOQuery everytime I select a Master Record with such as SQL Code ( for Example ) :

```
SELECT * FROM Detail WHERE MasterID = Master.ID
```

how can i do this without using ADOTable ( Master Source ) !?

in other words i want this Relationship be in DB Layer !

Comment: as I know, master-detail relations are commonly used with `TTable` descendant compoents. Do you actually need `TADOQuery` instead of `TADOTable`, which has `MasterSource` property?

Comment: "I dont want to Requery Detail ADOQuery everytime ..."  Why not?  If Sql Server is the back-end, any other type of dataset you might use is going to have to do that under the hood anyway.

Comment: "in other words i want this Relationship be in DB Layer !"  Then set up a stored procedure (or table-UDF) on the server that takes the MasterID as input and returns the detail records.  Your Delphi app is still going to have to invoke the stored proc/function, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to flatten the master detail relationship, you can do a [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) query to obtain all data from the 2 tables:

```
SELECT m.*, d.* FROM Master m INNER JOIN Detail d ON m.Id = d.MasterId
```

Comment: a view is better then asking the server for inner join as a surprise every time.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set up detail DataSet as usual and change the SQL to a parameterized one.    `SELECT * FROM details WHERE MasterID =: id`

This way only the corresponding details are loaded for each master record, which will throttle the load and keep displayed data more actual.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter propery of Tadoquery on detail table.

add this code to AfterScroll event of AdoQueryMaster;

```
AdoQueryDetail.filter := 'Where MasterID = ' +inttostr(AdoQueryMaster.fieldbyname('ID').asinteger);
AdoQueryDetail.filtered := true;
```